# Chromebook install Ubuntu but I can not to start Ubuntu. Acer C7

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, acer, chromebook

I followed all details in Johnny Phung's video [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer C710 Chromebook (Complete Guide)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qpjTzav3kw), but at the end of install and reboot steps, Ubuntu does not start.

This is the second computer that I have tried this with, but the first that gives me this problem. I am installing on an Acer C7.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 multiple times on my acer c710 chromebook and always came back to chrome os for my personal reason. The last time I tried to install it it worked but I had an internet problem. In any case, I don't think it's gonna be possible for you to install it because, in the guide, the guy says that he doesn't know how to change the amount of space you give ubuntu after install. If you need more space it won't be possible unless we figure out a way to change that. 
For my first time I gave it a good stable 260. You should do the same if you figure it out.