# Cannot boot. TPM Interrupt not working

Tags: boot, 22.04, cache

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Acer C720 Chromebook. When I cleared the cache, I tried to boot Ubuntu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which resulted in this screen:

[image: Boot Failure]

```
[    0.260118] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
[    1.825056] ata1.00: Read log 0x30 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
[    1.825281] ata1.00: Read log 0x30 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
/dev/sda3: recovering journal
/dev/sda3: clean, 225557/944704 files, 3646589/3777792 blocks
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There are a number of posts on AskUbuntu regarding the C720, which is not an ideal Linux machine. That said, you may be interested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/514075/1222991) regarding booting and suspend.

Comment: I and others get the tpm message every boot, I don't think that this is the problem. One method  to fix this is to add `rmmod tpm` at the top of the menuentry in GRUB. Here are some other things that can mess up a boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Answer (score 0):

Hello ik this post is old, but I was able to fix this issue and safely use the computer without any problems, the booting and everything is all good for now.