# Is it possible to dual-boot chrome OS and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, chromeos

I was wondering if I could dual-boot Ubuntu with Chrome OS and whether I need any special software/configuration to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Chrubuntu is a true dual boot and loads that way. Chrubuntu no longer works and will not be updated. It's potentially dangerous to install Chrubuntu on Chromebooks with newer models of Intel processors.

Crouton runs side by side with Chrome OS. Crouton is the better choice if you're not familiar with Ubuntu and just need a separate OS to launch some apps you need. You can run a music player app like Rhythmbox in Crouton and then switch back to ChromeOS in a matter of seconds for quick seamless browsing while it plays. Crouton also has less potential problems with glitchy device drivers for Chromebook hardware than Chrubuntu.

[chrx](https://chrx.org/) is a currently maintained project for dual booting various Linux distributions alongside ChromeOS. The default distribution is GalliumOS. GalliumOS is derived from Xubuntu and developed specifically for compatibility and optimized performance on Chromebook hardware. The downside of chrx is that it doesn't support ARM processors and firmware updates are required or recommended for newer models of Intel processors, so it's also more dangerous than Crouton.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is done on chrome books all the time with chrubuntu. Installing it on a desktop system would be easier without the partitioning security.

Answer (score 1):

Yes dual boot is possible whether that's using a USB to store Ubuntu or partitioning the Chromebook's internal drive to store both OS's. There are a couple of open source heroes that have made this possible and you will need to use their utilities to get this working. I have included the main steps here:

**Option1: Dual boot Chrome OS and Ubuntu on a USB drive**

1. Enable Developer mode.
2. Modify the Chromebooks BIOS (I recommend you use the utility from [Mr Chromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) and use the RW_Legacy option).
3. Leave ChromeOS as is on the internal drive and install Ubuntu on a permanently plugged in USB drive.
4. On boot, use **Ctrl + D to boot into Chrome OS** and use **Ctrl + L to boot into Ubuntu**.
5. Be warned, there may be some hardware that doesn't work like sound on BayTrail Chromebooks.

I have created a written/video guide for how to [dual boot Chrome OS and Ubuntu on a USB drive](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/_askcaptain/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux/) which show you the whole process from start to finish.

**Option 2: Dual boot Chrome OS and Ubuntu on the Chromebook's internal drive**

1. Enable Developer mode
2. Modify the Chromebooks BIOS (I recommend you use the utility from [Mr Chromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) and use the RW_Legacy option).
3. Partition your SSD, download and install Linux (You will need to use the [chrx](https://chrx.org/) utility which partitions the drive, downloads your chosen Linux distro and installs it for you from within Chrome OS).
4. Be warned, there may be some hardware that doesn't work like sound on BayTrail Chromebooks.

I have created a written/video guide for how to [dual boot a Chromebook on the internal drive](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/_askcaptain/how-do-i-dual-boot-a-chromebook-on-the-internal-drive/) which show you the whole process from start to finish.