# Snapd isn't working

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, intellij

I want to install intellij idea. I tried:

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic 
[sudo] password for user-1099869:  
error: cannot communicate with server: 
Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/intellij-idea-community: 
dial unixtr /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I'd posted abut this before and was told to reinstall snapd.

I did

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

I tested the hello world snapd. Got the same error as before:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: 
Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello-world: 
dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

If I try

```
snap version
```

it removes "user-10998699@localhost" and allows me to type anything even new lines, the same happens with

```
snap list
```

Someone asked if this was really Ubuntu 16.04. I'm on a chromebook where I  installed Crouton. https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/

Update(feb 18, 2021):

```
systemctl start snapd.socket
```

gets me:

```
  Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: 
No such file or directory
    Failed to start snapd.socket: Launch helper exited with unknown return
 code 1
    See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.socket' for details.
```

I do

```
systemctl status snapd.socket
```

get:

```
Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I tried:

```
sudo service snapd start
```

got:

```
snapd: unrecognized service
```

I did:

```
sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
```

seemed to work

then

systemctl start snapd.socket

and got

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the `snapd` service is running? What do you see with `snap version` or `snap list`?

Comment: snap version removes user97979@local host and allows me to type anything even new lines

Comment: snap list does the same

Comment: Add information to your question, not to comments. Comments are how we ask you to improve the question so it's answerable. Is this really an Ubuntu 16.04 system? Is it stock Ubuntu? Or a "based-on" derivative? Is is customized?

Comment: `systemctl start snapd.socket` requires root permissions like `sudo systemctl start snapd.socket`. The `Running in chroot, ignoring request.` error message occurred because Crouton is a chroot. Start off by debugging something simple like the hello-world snap to check if you can get any snap to run in Crouton. If not you'll have to switch from Crouton to [chrx](https://chrx.org/). For more info: https://askubuntu.com/a/866637/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the snap service running.

Once you've installed snap (`sudo apt install snapd`), you've only installed snap, you haven't done anything to run it, or autostart when your computer starts up.

You also want to do:
`systemctl start snapd.socket` - To run snap, so you can execute commands.

`systemctl enable snapd.socket` - To have snap to run on startup.

---

I just tested by stopping `snapd.socket` myself (`systemctl stop snapd.socket`) and while the service was stopped, I experienced similar behavior to what you described.